# In Cakephp, how to retrieve the name of one of the models being used in a view?

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a print_coupon.ctp file that I would like to use for coupons from any of my coupon categories....restaurants, nightclubs, golf courses, etc (these all have their own Models).  In my controller, I have this logic:

```
 public function print_all_coupons() {
      $this->layout ='couponlayout';
      $this->set('title', 'Print all coupons for Gulf Shores');
      $this->Coupon->recursive=2;
     $this->paginate['Coupon']=array(
                'limit'=>9,
                'order'=>array(
                    'id'=>'asc'
                    ),
                'conditions'=>array(
                        'OR'=>array(
                            'expires' =>0,
                            'Coupon.end_date >'=>date('Y-m-d')
                        ))
                );
        $c=$this->paginate('Coupon');
      $this->set('printcoupons', $c);
      }
```

This allows me to see up the ladder as any coupon belongsTo Restaurant, Golf Course, Nightclub, User, etc.  Normally in my view for printing say a restaurant coupon, I'd retrieve my data by saying something like

```
echo $h['Restaurant']['Location']['address'];
```

which works great, for just restaurants.  I'd like to be able to get a variable from the controller that would let me change out whatever the model is that the coupon pertains to, like this:

```
echo $h['$someModel']['Location']['address'];
```

Surely this is possible in Cakephp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the related models? These are available as an array in `$this->params->models`.

**EDIT:**

If I understand correctly you want to `echo` the locations for some associated models? `$this->params->models` contains an associative array of related models. The associated models array for your CouponModel could look like the following:

```
Array
(
    [Restaurant] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [className] => Restaurant
        )

    [GolfCourse] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [className] => GolfCourse
        )

    [Nightclub] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [className] => Nightclub
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [className] => User
        )

)
```

You can then loop over this array and get the location of each model. I've stored the models and each className in a variable, for clarity's sake.

```
<?php
  $associatedModels = $this->params->models;
  foreach ($associatedModels as $model) :
    $className = $model['className'];
    echo $h[$className]['Location']['address'];
  endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Do you think you could explain that to me?  I am new to cakephp.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working, as the loop is causing it to return Restaurant.Location.address (which works), then Coupon.Location.address (doesn't exist), User.Location.address(nope), etc.  I think the best course of action for me is to establish a direct relationship with the model I'm after.  Like, I can say that Location hasMany coupons, Coupon hasOne Image, etc and then instead of trying to call up Restaurant's img1 or GolfCourse's Location address, I can just use the Coupon model.  Do you think this is advisable?

Comment: That could work, but you would have to test it. Also, I'm not certain what your pagination result array looks like, so my update was only a theoretical example. ;)

Comment: I tested it on coupons from two different models, and it does work.  It seems inelegant to me, but being a noob, clumsy and awkward is ok if it works for  now.  Thank you so much for your help, and since you supplied me with a way to see my related models, I am marking your answer as accepted.